# Regular expression for a finite automaton appears to be wrong

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

For the following finite state machine:

[image]

The language recognized by it is given to be: $0+(10+11)(0+1)^*$ in my samples book, which I think is clearly wrong, since there's no return path to the final state.

I think the language recognized should be just an epsilon or nothing. I wanted to confirm if I am right or wrong with the answer.

Comment: You may only consider there is a typo in your book and that the final state should be $C$. But then the language recognized by the automaton should be $(0+(10+11))(0+1)^*$.

Comment: You have already pretty much proven that that solution is wrong. What more do you need?

Comment: Considering your analysis of the automaton with the typo: "...an epsilon or *nothing*". If a finite automaton represents the empty language then all its accepting states must be unreachable from the start state, and this is clearly not the case here.

Comment: As JEP shows, the book contains two typos. What book does not? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

As given FA is DFA. It is accepting string only $\{\epsilon \}$.

And, complement of given  DFA accepting : 
$\implies (1+0+1(0+1))(0+1)^*= (1+0+(10+11))(0+1)^*$

$\implies 1(0+1)^*+0(0+1)^*+(10+11)(0+1)^* = (0+1)^+ =$ { accepting everything other than $\{\epsilon \}$ string over alphabet $\{0,1\}$}.